# Symfony2: создание пользовательского типа поля с таким же именем. как у встроенного типа

Tags: php, symfony2

Работаю с Symfony 2.8.3.

Читал вот эти ресурсы:
- [How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)
- [Symfony2: Overriding a built-in field type with a custom field type having the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673275/symfony2-overriding-a-built-in-field-type-with-a-custom-field-type-having-the-s)
и многие другие, к. были представлены в этих источниках (не могу много ссылок размещать).

Необходимо создать такой тип поля **date**, к. бы отвечал требованиям заказчика по многим параметрам, в т.ч. и по формату даты. Причем, этот (мой, новый) тип должен использоваться везде (!!) в проекте, даже сторонними бандлами.

Создаю класс:

```
class DateType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType {
    // тут переопределяю нужные мне методы
}
```

Прописываю его в сервисе:

```
services:
    #...
    form.type.date:
        class: Application\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: date }
    #...
```

и использую в форме:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('birthday', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => 'form.label.birthday',
            'translation_domain' => $this->translation_domain,
            'required' => true,
            'invalid_message' => 'form.error.birthday',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'datepicker without-error-text',
            ),
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        ));
}
```

Однако такой код выбрасывает исключение:

> The field type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType" is not registered with the service container.

Как же не зарегистрирован?!! А, да, таки не зарегистрирован. Я же свой тип регистрирую вместо встроенного.

В одном из ответов в вопросе, ссылку на к. я привел ранее, был дан совет принудительно регистрировать свой тип, вмешавшись в работу компилятора зависимостей.

Ок, делаю.

Создаю свой компилятор:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('form.type.date');
        $definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType');
    }
}
```

Использую его при построеннии главного бандла:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/AcmeDemoBundle.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Однако успеха мне это не приносит. Снова получаю исключение, правда уже другое:

> The type name specified for the service "form.type.date" does not match the actual name. Expected "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType", given "Application\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType"

Как показало исследование кода, исключение бросает Sonata-project из разных бандлов. В проекте я использую их админку и их блоки. Т.е. это они не могут создать поле типа date, потому что натыкаются на разницу в названии классов.

Подскажите, плз, что я упускаю или делаю не так?

Спасибо.

P.S. Большая просьба НЕ спрашивать, зачем мне надо то или это. Если можете помочь/подсказать, помогите/подскажите. Нет - лучше промолчите.

P.S.S. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема именно в `SonataAdminBundle`. Там есть конкретные хардкоденные значения для стандартных типов. Разработчиков понять можно: они даже и не думали, что кому-то вздумается менять стандартные симфонийские типы.

Чтобы провернуть Ваше хитрое дельце, необходимо переопределить маппинг стандартных типов, а также сонатовский тип `DatePicker` (если используете его, конечно же), который явно ссылается на симфонийский тип даты.

#### Переопределяем маппинг типов

Сделать это можно двумя способами:

**Через конфиг:**

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    form:
        mapping:
            type:
                date: 'Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType'
```

**Через явную подгрузку в коде:**

Для этого Вам необходимо в любой момент после загрузки сонатовского бандла вызвать метод:

```
Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\FormHelper::registerFormTypeMapping(
    ['date' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType']
);
```

Этот способ удобнее в том случае, если Вам все же нужно иногда дать дать сонате разгуляться.

#### Переопределяем сонатовский тип DatePicker

Опять лезем в компайлер-пасс и затираем значение класса для сервиса:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php
$definition = $container->getDefinition('sonata.core.form.type.date_picker');
$definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType');
```

Не забываем также создать этот класс:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/Type/DatePickerType.php
class DatePickerType extends Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType {

    public function getParent()
    {
        return method_exists('Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType', 'getBlockPrefix') ?
           'Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType' : // Тут должен быть FQCN Вашей реализации типа
           'date' // SF <2.8 BC
        ;
    }

}
```